# How to handle specific json error

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, mysqli

When I try to create a json string out of an array I get the following error: 
**"Error = 5 Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded"**
Though my table contains only strings with utf8_unicode_ci attributes or integers. Also, when I var_dump the array there is nothing to complain about.

Also I tried mysqli_set_charset("utf8",$con); right after I created my connection. It did not help though.

How should I fix this error?

Answer (score -1):

You may consider casting it to an array just to be sure.

```
$arr = (array)$arr;
```

Your question is a bit too vague to give substantial help.